# Why are place names in London showing up in Japanese on maps.google.co.uk?

Tags: google-maps, translation

This is rather odd - I noticed recently that various street names and places in London are being labelled in Japanese (Katakana) on Google Maps (on maps.google.co.uk).

For example, [Vauxhall](https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=Vauxhall+Bridge+Road,+London&aq=1&sll=53.800651,-4.064941&sspn=20.824402,57.084961&ie=UTF8&hq=&hnear=Vauxhall+Bridge+Rd,+London,+United+Kingdom&ll=51.48605,-0.123607&spn=0.002669,0.006968&z=18):

[image]

I found [mention of the same issue on this local forum](http://www.se23.com/forum/showthread.php?tid=4554) from a few weeks ago (for Southwark station in that case).

Is this an experimental feature that I've got enabled by mistake?

Is is possible to switch it off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely because it was added that way (in Japanese) by a user, by editing the place (http://www.google.com/help/maps/edit/).

Comment: I guess you're right.  I've submitted edits for the ones I've found back into English.  Let the edit the edit wars commence!

Comment: (it does seem strange that there's not an interface to select which language you prefer, since from the edit history it's aware of the different language labels)